# How does Apache Ignite partition the spatial data?

Tags: ignite

I ran a geospatial query on Apache Ignite successfully. But I didn't understand how their partitioning work. How does Apache Ignite partition the spatial data among nodes when we use *PARTITIONED* CacheMode? Do they use any partitioning technique like Grid or Quad-tree? I saw that they are creating 1024 partitions for each data set. How can I change the number of partitions? I already read their documents but I didn't find anything about this. Any suggestion or document links will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partitioning is performed on key basis using [Rendezvous hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendezvous_hashing). Apache Ignite is key-value based.

You can change its properties by specifying [affinityFunction](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation#affinity-function) in CacheConfiguration.

Partitioning is usually wholly unrelated to spatial indexing since spatial index is secondary.